# How to Automatically Monitor Windows Event Log from SQL Server winth Windows 2008 R2 installed

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008, event-log

I need to figure out an automated way of monitoring the application event log of SQL Server boxes. The requirement is such that the system should generate a summarized report of SQL Server errors and warnings from the target machines' event log and send it to the DBA.

Comment: `monitoring windows event log` in google brings up both commercial free (e.g. http://www.eventsentry.com/features/event-log-monitoring) and source solutions. Have you tested any of them?

Answer (score 0):

I found mssqltips link 
[Monitor event viewer from sql server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1915/how-to-automatically-monitor-windows-event-log-from-sql-server/)
. I didnt try this , but it might be helpful for you. Its a big solution so instead coying whloe thing , marking link

Comment: Hi.. Thanks..The link you provided will work with Windows Server 2003 only. Unfortunately Windows Server 2008 no longer comes with the eventquery.vbs script file. Please suggest for Windows Server 2008.